# what is the windows keyboard equivalent to command right bracket when tabbing blocks of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, cloud9-ide, tabbing

what is the windows keyboard equivalent to command and right bracket when tabbing blocks of code?  I'm using Cloud9 for an online class and the teach uses a Mac to tab code in Ruby and I was curious if there is a Windows keyboard equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If by tabbing code you mean indenting, you can use `tab` and `shift-tab`shortcuts, you can also modify shortcuts from keybindings menu, to disable `ctrl-[`/`]` keys for `tableft`/`tabright` commands, and allow `blockindent` `blockoutdent` commands to use it.